# Android_Ntlm - problem with passing Domain name

Tags: android, okhttp, ntlm-authentication

For NTLM authentication I am using an external library https://github.com/netcosports/Android_Ntlm

When I don’t transfer the domain
like this

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder ()
                 .authenticator (new NTLMAuthenticator (userName, password, null))
                 .build ();
```

Works fine

But When I pass domain like this

```
String userDomain = “ourdomain”;
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder ()
                 .authenticator (new NTLMAuthenticator (userName, password, userDomain))
                 .build ();
```

I get an error

> Too many follow-up requests

Comment: This Lib has this issue you can check GitHub issue of this lib https://github.com/netcosports/Android_Ntlm/issues/3

Comment: I added that issue a minute ago